# SQL query Generated by Excel function is not working

Tags: sql, excel, function

Hi I am having trouble with excel sql query where i m getting values from SQL DB based on values in my excel table. so i write a function in excel which will put all the values in a query and sql connection will run and pull data matching that value. the problem i am having is ("") as SQL doesn't like this and like 'value' but i have changing it to make it single '' but excel function doesn't like it. 
here is what i write in  excel function.

```
="SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM [SERVER].[dbo].[Table] WHERE

" &TS[[#Headers],[Currency]] & " = """&[@Currency] &""""  
&  
"AND " &TS[[#Headers],[Type]]& " = """&[@Type]&""""  
&  
"AND " &TS[[#Headers],[Report]]& " = """&[@Report ]&""""  
&  
"AND " &TS[[#Headers],[Status]]& " = """&[@Status]&""""      
&  
"AND " &TS[[#Headers],[Target]]& " = """&[@Target]&""""
```

which then changes into this.

```
"SELECT TOP 1 NAME FROM [SERVER].[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE 
Currency = ""EUR""
AND Type = "" 0"" AND  Report  = ""9"" AND  Status = ""0"" AND Target  = ""Reversal"""
```

here is my Table example:

```
Type    Report  Status       Target          Currency
 0       9        0         Reversal         EUR
 0       9        0          ACCEPT          CHI
 0       9        0          NEW             EUR
 0       9        0          OLD             YEN
```

my VB Function is:

```
Function Download_Standard_BOM(Query As String)
'Initializes variables
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String

ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=STORESYSTEM 
;Database=STORE;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

cnn.Open ConnectionString
StrQuery = Query 'Sheets("Tests Scenario").Range("J2").Offset(i, 0).Value
cnn.CommandTimeout = 100
rst.Open StrQuery, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
Download_Standard_BOM = rst("NAME")

End Function
```

Comment: This shouldn't be happening AFAIK.  Two double quotes means a literal double quote inside an Excel formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the below function into your VBA

```
Public Function SQLText(RawText As Variant) As String
    If Not RawText = vbNullString Then
        SQLText = "'" & Replace(RawText, "'", "''") & "'"
    Else
        SQLText = "Null"
    End If
End Function
```

Where you reference your column in Excel, wrap the column name in SQLText(*yourcolumn*)

EDIT:
Referencing one of your columns

" &TS[[#Headers],[Currency]] & " = **"& SQLTEXT([@Currency]) & ""**

Comment: Thanks for your response this is my excel function which is having compile error with the following excel problem:

Comment: under the same VBA function as my SQL connection one or on any sheet?

Comment: separate vba function. You can then call the SQLText one from your one.

Comment: thank you, it worked for me it replaced the "" with ' ' :) many thanks but i am having another issue now iwth my VBA connection i think its telling me a compile error can you please take a look at my VBA connection function? its in the main question

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that your SQL fields are already being escaped by double quotes.  If so, then removing the double escaping visible in your Excel formula above should resolve the issue:

```
="SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM [SERVER].[dbo].[Table] WHERE "
&TS[[#Headers],[Currency]] & " = "&[@Currency] 
&" AND " &TS[[#Headers],[Type]]& " = "&[@Type] 
&" AND " &TS[[#Headers],[Report]]& " = "&[@Report] 
&" AND " &TS[[#Headers],[Status]]& " = "&[@Status]  
&" AND " &TS[[#Headers],[Target]]& " = "&[@Target]
```

By the way, even if this fixes your immediate problem, you should keep in mind that in most flavors of SQL single, not double, quotes are used to indicate string literals.